# What movies should be seen prior to The Flash?

Tags: dc, suggested-order, dc-extended-universe, batman-1989, the-flash-2023

As I understand it, The Flash merges content from both the DCEU and some older movies such as the Michael Keaton Batman movies.

What movies or TV shows should one watch prior to seeing The Flash?

Comment: I'm ideally looking for an answer from someone who has actually watched the movie, not just from marketing materials and interviews.

Comment: I'd advise that you watch *Schindler's List* and *The Shawshank Redemeption* before you watch The Flash. Then at least you'll have seen two films that aren't awful.

Comment: Citizen Kane is highly regarded,

Comment: I have seen The Flash and I confirm that you do not need to watch any other DC movie before.

Comment: @ClintEastwood - And while that's true, only time will tell whether critics will hold *The Flash* in such high esteem.

Answer (score 7):

The AV Club has recently published an article on [this very question](https://www.avclub.com/the-flash-viewing-guide-in-as-few-movies-as-possible-1850504982).

For what it's worth, these are their suggestions...

Essential:

- *Batman (1989)*
- *Man of Steel (2013)*
- *Zack Snyder’s Justice League (2021)* - i.e. "The Snyder cut"

For the completist:

- *Batman V. Superman: Dawn Of Justice (2016)*

Extra credit:

- *Back To The Future (1985)*
- *An Evening With Kevin Smith (2002)* - I think this is in relation to a specific cameo in *The Flash*, based on an unmade project of the late 1990s, which is discussed here

Although if you're going to count *Back to the Future* as a prerequisite, I guess you could also watch *Birdman (2014)*, since it provides some meta-commentary on Michael Keaton playing Batman again!

Comment: I think one is better off just watching Birdman and ignoring all the rest, Flash itself in particular ;>

Comment: The original *Batman* for sure, but *Man of Steel*?  Ugh.

Comment: I'm quite puzzled about the last two. Perhaps I'll have to have a look at the article for the reasons.

Comment: I found it quite funny when Michael Keaton played the Vulture in Spider-Man, only three years after Birdman; and now he's back to play Batman, it was even more fun recognising him.

Answer (score 3):

I watched the movie a couple days ago. You don't need to see any other movies before this one. That being said, I basically agree with JayFor's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/276454/106383).
The Flash is a continuation of the story from Justice League, but the plot is not dependent on that movie or any others. It does feature characters and events from other DC movies:

- Batman (1989)
- > Batman & Robin
- Man of Steel
- Justice League
- > Aquaman
- > Wonder Woman

The Flash does in fact contain a reference to Back to the Future. The only thing you need to know about BttF is that it starred Michael J. Fox. I've never seen An Evening with Kevin Smith, but I believe I know which scene in The Flash referenced it.